# Neo4j - reco : Engine FriendsComputingEngine wasn't found on the classpath

Tags: java, neo4j, graphaware

I am using [neo4j-reco](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-reco), to pre-compute real-time recommendations.

I have a sample graph and .jar files have been placed into the plugins directory of Neo4j installation as mentioned in the readme file,
but getting following error when restarting the server.

```
2015-12-01 15:38:35.769+0530 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
15:38:35.788 [Thread-12] INFO  c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper - stopped
2015-12-01 15:38:35.789+0530 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
15:38:36.399 [Thread-12] INFO  c.g.runtime.BaseGraphAwareRuntime -  Shutting down GraphAware Runtime... 
15:38:36.399 [Thread-12] INFO  c.g.r.schedule.RotatingTaskScheduler - Terminating task scheduler...
15:38:36.399 [Thread-12] INFO  c.g.r.schedule.RotatingTaskScheduler - Task scheduler terminated successfully.
15:38:36.399 [Thread-12] INFO  c.g.runtime.BaseGraphAwareRuntime - GraphAware Runtime shut down.
2015-12-01 15:38:36.405+0530 INFO  Successfully stopped database
2015-12-01 15:38:36.405+0530 INFO  Successfully shutdown database
15:38:40.041 [main] INFO  c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension - GraphAware Runtime enabled, bootstrapping...
15:38:40.069 [main] INFO  c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension - Bootstrapping module with order 1, ID reco, using com.graphaware.reco.neo4j.module.RecommendationModuleBootstrapper
15:38:40.077 [main] INFO  c.g.r.n.m.RecommendationModuleBootstrapper - Constructing new recommendation module with ID: reco
15:38:40.080 [main] INFO  c.g.r.n.m.RecommendationModuleBootstrapper - Trying to instantiate class FriendsComputingEngine
15:38:40.089 [main] ERROR c.g.r.n.m.RecommendationModuleBootstrapper - Engine FriendsComputingEngine wasn't found on the classpath. Will not pre-compute recommendations
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FriendsComputingEngine
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) ~[na:1.7.0_91]
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build one first if you're referring to it in your config. If you follow the steps in the readme file you're mentioning, you will end up building one.